# Select2 - Get Value with event mouseenter

Tags: jquery, yii2, jquery-select2, mouseenter, kartik-v

I'm using `Select2` with 5 `optgroup` how can I get the "value" (id) by hovering over each item with the event `mouseenter`?

```
$('body').on("mouseenter", ".select2-results__option", function(e){
    console.log(value);
});
```

I'm using Select2 with Kartik for Yii2 Framework.

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'id_nconform')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
            'data' => $variables,
            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a state ...'],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'allowClear' => true
            ],
        ]);
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'e' argument you pass to your event callback has a target property holding the current targetted input of the event.
From there, you can access its value.

```js
$('body').on("mouseenter", ".test", function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="test">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>


<select class="test">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT after receiving more precise details about the problem**:

You can't interact with html select's options.

The solution then would be to mock a select with some custom html/css/js combo.
You can check some idea of result here : https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

Even though you're not using this framework, it's just an example. You can then interact freely with each part of your select.

Comment: the value is always 0. :(

Comment: Then check your generated html to verify that your input is well built. I edited my answer so you can see a working example.

Comment: i need "mouseenter" in each option with open dropdown and optgroups

Comment: You can't bind events to options in a select box... The only solution then is to mock a select with html, css ans js because you won't be able to interact with options in a standard html select.

Comment: I edited my answer so you can mark it as the answer and close the question.